# Python unable to pass python requests CSV Output with StringIO

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, httprequest

Im new into python programming. I was trying to query API using requests module and would like to pass that output  as input to python pandas module and would like to get min, max and average data.

Im getting the below error while executing the code.  Using print command I can see the data fetched from the requests.get. But While i pass that data as input Im receiving the error "<_io.StringIO Object at 0x7f7b00049e58>"

```
Code Snip:
#!/bin/python3
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO
with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        HMC=row['HMC']
        FRAME=row['FRAME']
        LPAR=row['LPAR'] 
        PARAMS = {'host':HMC, 'mname':Frame, 'lpar':LPAR}
        r = r.requests.get("https://localhost:12443/lpar2rrd-cgi/lpar2rrd-rep.sh", params=PARAMS, 
        verify=false)
        print(r.text)
        data = StringIO(r.text) ## Also tried with (r.url) 
        print(data)
        df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')
        p = df['CPU Cores Utilization'].max()
        q = df['CPU Cores Utilization'].min()
        avg = df['CPU Cores Utilization'].mean()
        print(p, q, avg)
csv_file.close()

sample.csv file content:
HMC,FRAME,LPAR
HMC101,9119-MME,LPAR10
HMC101,9119-MME,LPAR20
HMC101,8284-42A,LPAR22
```

Comment: *off-topic*: your last line `csv_file.close()` is useless as you use a context manager `with ...`

Comment: Can you update your post with the `traceback` and a sample of `r.text`, please?

Comment: sure.. I will execute and provide the output.

Comment: @Corralien Could you give me any sample code for traceback. I never tried it

Comment: The traceback is the full error message, not just the type of the exception.

Comment: @Corralien Thank you for the update. I will try to capture and share